# Watch Twitch Live Stream in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, twitch

I want to do a simple JavaFX application to watch Twitch Live Streams.

So far, I come up with 3 possible solutions:

1)  JavaFX WebView. With it I was successful to watch Twitch clip video, but Live Steaming seems not supported.

Code:

```
public class App extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        WebView webview = new WebView();
        webview.getEngine().load(
                "https://www.twitch.tv/stariy_bog/clip/RelievedPopularYakinikuDancingBanana"
        );
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        webview.setPrefSize(640, 390);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(webview));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

2)  JavaFX scene.media package. I’ve found this package in JavaFX documentation: it states that HLS Live Streaming is supported, but I’ve found no success in loading any Twitch channel.

Code:

```
public class MediaTest extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        String uri = "https://www.twitch.tv/qsnake";
        try {
            primaryStage.setTitle("Embedded Media Player");
            Group root = new Group();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 540, 210);

            Media media = new Media(uri);
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
            mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
            // create mediaView and add media player to the viewer
            MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
            ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(mediaView);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.sizeToScene();
            primaryStage.show();
            mediaPlayer.setOnPlaying(() -> {
                System.out.println(mediaPlayer.getMedia().getDuration().toString());
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

3)  Twitch Developers API. Did not found any information about live steams using Java here so far.


Also, yes, I’ve searched web about this problem. For example I’ve found a [topic](https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/playing-twitch-video-in-javafx-webview/10002), but it OPs problem was not resolved.

Comment: For the second one, you need to give it the path to the live stream (m3u8) not the page.

Comment: @szatmary, could you please provide an example of such path?

Comment: Just view the network tab in the browser debug tools and filter for m3u8 files.